# python equivalent of HttpClient in java wth sql query

Tags: java, python, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need some help to translate the java code into Python.

I am not quite familiar with the Java code. I have some legacy java code that I have to rewrite in Python. Basically, it is about reading some data from a server. Java code uses httpClient with some SQL queries. I would like the right module I shall use in python, e.g., pyodbc, urllib, or requests.

```
    HttpClient httpClient = getThreadSafeClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://someserver:9997/the_store/query/");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(
            "select what_i_need from store.data where date=20190722"));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

I would like to know what python equivalent code for the java code above. Thanks.

Comment: The query part is irrelevant, it's just an http post payload. IMHO the easiest method would be to use `requests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in Python using `requests`

I'm taking this from one of my projects, I used a get request, but post syntax should look like this.

If you need authentication you need to define `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`

```
   import requests
   from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
   import time

   def send_request(post_url):
      print(post_url)
      try:
         session = requests.Session()
         response = session.post(post_url,data=dict(), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
         if(response.status_code == 200):
            return response.text
         elif(response.status_code == 429):
           print("API exhaust was reached, please wait for 30 seconds")        
           time.sleep(30)      
           return send_request(post_url)                   
         else:
           print response.status_code
           return None 
      except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
         print(e)
         print("HTTP Request failed!")   
      return None
```

**Note:**

`data` accepts a `dict()`, you can send your payload with json format by using `json="your_json_formatted_sql_query"` in place of `data=dict()`